# Por que os números dos outputs do R saem sempre com ponto (.)?

Tags: r

Ao obter percentuais e respectivos IC95% o output obtenho como abaixo:

```
> observed<-c(95,1202,26,921)
> require(DescTools)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: DescTools
> MultinomCI(observed,conf.level=0.95,method="sisonglaz")
            est     lwr.ci     upr.ci
[1,] 0.04233512 0.02094474 0.06449834
[2,] 0.53565062 0.51426025 0.55781385
[3,] 0.01158645 0.00000000 0.03374968
[4,] 0.41042781 0.38903743 0.43259103
```

Esses **est**(estimados) e respectivos IC95% são, na verdade 4,233512%, 53,565062% etc, escritos dessa maneira (0.04233512, 0.53565062). Precisei multiplicar por 100 esses valores do output ou, simplesmente deslocar a vírgula 2 casas para a direita.

Como faço para o output me retornar o valores sem necessidade de eu multiplicá-los por 100 ou deslocar a vírgula?

Fico perdido com esses números por que às vezes gero OR(odds ratio) e outras estimativas e não sei quando preciso multiplicar (ou deslocar a vírgula) e quando não preciso.

Comment: Esses valores *"são, na verdade 4,2%, 53,6% etc"*: **não, não são**. É assim que não fica perdido, sabendo o que está a fazer. Ninguém multiplica *"por 100%"*, basta ouvir o som disso: cem por cento. Isto dá `100 por 100`, que é `1`. Quando muito multiplica-se por 100, para efeitos de apresentação dos resultados, mas para fazer as contas utilizam-se números reais.

Comment: Voto para fechar esta pergunta porque não faz sentido nenhum, não há nada de útil para o AP muito menos para outros no futuro.

Comment: Obrigado! Noto que a linguagem R gera os resultados dessa forma (0.xx) na escala de 0 a 1. E para melhor inteligibilidade, tem que considerar duas casas decimais, i.e, multiplicar por 100, independente da unidade.

Answer (score 0):

Os números formatados como percentagens são utilizados para efeitos de apresentação ou de publicação, não são números com os quais se possam fazer contas, isto é, não são números. Não é só uma questão de escala.

Com os dados da pergunta,

```
library(DescTools)

observed <- c(95, 1202, 26, 921)
ci95 <- MultinomCI(observed, conf.level= 0.95, method = "sisonglaz")
```

pode-se usar as funções de formatação do pacote CRAN [`scales`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=scales) para apresentar strings como percentagens.

```
perc95 <- scales::percent(ci95, trim = FALSE)
matrix(perc95, nrow = nrow(ci95))
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#[1,] " 4.23%" " 2.09%" " 6.45%"
#[2,] "53.57%" "51.43%" "55.78%"
#[3,] " 1.16%" " 0.00%" " 3.37%"
#[4,] "41.04%" "38.90%" "43.26%"
```

Answer (score -1):

Noto que a linguagem R gera os resultados dessa forma (0.xx) na escala de 0 a 1. E para melhor inteligibilidade, ou seja, para levar à escala de 0 a 100, tem que considerar duas casas decimais, i.e, multiplicar por 100.